# My WordPress plugin works on local server, not on production

Tags: wordpress

My basic WordPress plugin checks referrer and sets session data (like a phone number associated to referrer domain). It works fine on my local server, but doesn't even get called on production server (which I don't have access to and has many other plugins installed)

Here's what I have:

```
// loads config and sets session vars depending on referrer domain
// do I use"init" or "wp" ?
add_action("init", "aw_refer_init", 1);

// used in templates to grab session a session var
add_action("aw_refer_get", "aw_refer_get", 5, 2);
```

I've checked the basics (http://yoast.com/plugin-not-working/) but everything checks out.
Any ideas?

Comment: you don't have access to the production server? I don't understand.

Comment: The plugin is for a specific site. The site webmaster is installing the plugin, we've done screen share so that he can show me what he's doing.  It's really baffling me.

Comment: hard to check out the error if you can debug directly and the environment is different from your development side.

Answer (score 0):

Replace...

wp-config.php file 's define('WP_DEBUG', false);

part with

// Turns WordPress debugging on

define('WP_DEBUG', true);

// Tells WordPress to log everything to the /wp-content/debug.log file

define('WP_DEBUG_LOG', true);

// Doesn't force the PHP 'display_errors' variable to be on

define('WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', false);

// Hides errors from being displayed on-screen

@ini_set('display_errors', 0);

---

Then run the project in live server it will give you error in log file
check it in
wp-content/debug.log file and do appropriate